# Design problem with MVC 3.0 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View User :

```
public class User {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }    
}
```

I created a login View (strongly typed User)...
But my Login view has others attributes, like RememberMe checkbox... That attribute does not belong to User Model...

So, how is the best way to deal with that?  Creating a new UserViewModel with all View attributes is an option, but I think its not the best way...

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how is the best way to deal with that?

By using a view model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }  
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }  
}
```

Strongly typing a login partial to a User model hardly makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, and where that ViewModel will stay? In the same project as Models?

Comment: @Paul, view models belong to the MVC application tier as they are strongly tied to their corresponding view. The `Models` folder seems like a good place to put them in.

Comment: Thanks Darin... What you think about dont creating that ViewModel, but only adding the RememberMe on View method, like : public ActionResult Index(User user, bool RememberMe)  ?   It works great, but I dont know about best pratices ...

Comment: @Paul, personally I always create view models whether it is as input or output to controller actions. Your approach will also work. I can't say which one would be better as this would be subjective. I can only tell you what I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

For best practices I would suggest you use a ViewModel as Darin suggested. Also u can create a factory for copying ViewModel to Entity. Reflection is a bit too much here.

Here is just Darin Dimitrov example in detail.

```
    public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required] ... and other validation
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public static class UserFactory
{
    public static User GetUserFromModel(LoginViewModel m, User u)
    {
        u.Username = m.Username;
        u.Password = m.Password;
        return u;
    }
}

public class UserController : DefaultController
{
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel m)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User u = UserFactory.GetUserFromModel(m);
            ....code ...
        }
        ... code...
    }

}
```

@Darin sorry for highjacking your example, I remember having a bit of hard time with this myself so just want to help